# Как настроить письмо для кнопки "Отписаться" в ящике?

Tags: email

Как настроить письмо, что бы в ящике для этого письма появилась кнопка "Отписаться"? Пробовал применять заголовок List-Unsubscribe: `<https://www.***>` но кнопка не появлялась. Но видел письма рассылок с кнопкой но без заголовка List-Unsubscribe.

Comment: В каком ящике? У каждого почтового клиента/провайдера своё собственное поведение

Comment: Эту функциональность должен поддерживать почтовый сервис, каждый поддерживает её немного по-разному.